# How to map a function over a dataframe field that is a list

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by, split

I have spent hours troubleshooting this and really appreciate your help!

Each node can have multiple activities, and each activity can have up to two associated grades, which were an ARRAY type in SQL. My goal is to get the minimum activity grade for each node. I imported the ACTIVITY_GRADE field using ARRAY_TO_STRING(ACTIVITY_GRADE) AS ACTIVITY_GRADE (there might be a better way to import it to make it a list I can iterate over?)

The data looks like the below, and my goal is to get the last column as it is shown: min_node_grade.

```
STUDENT_ID RECORD_ID      NODE_NAME ACTIVITY_NAME  ACTIVITY_GRADE       GOAL = GET THIS min_node_grade
FredID     gobbledeegook1   Node1   MyActivity1    PreK, Kindergarten   PreK
FredID     gobbledeegook2   Node1   MyActivity1    Kindergarten         PreK
FredID     gobbledeegook3   Node2   MyActivity2    1st Grade            1st Grade
JaniceID   gobbledeegook4   Node3   MyActivity3    Kindergarten         Kindergarten
JaniceID   gobbledeegook5   Node3   MyActivity3    1st Grade            Kindergarten
```

I have gone a likely unnecessarily complicated route. How can I create a function that will map the grade_to_index dictionary across each value of the comma-separated string that is ACTIVITY_GRADE, take the minimum for that activity, then group by node and take the min over the node's activities?

```
#split it into two columns
df[['activity_grade_a', 'activity_grade_b']] = df.ACTIVITY_GRADE.str.split(",", expand = True)

#map it to integers so can take min to identify grade
grade_to_index = {"Preschool": -2, "Pre-K": -1, "Kindergarten": 0, "1st Grade": 1, '2nd Grade':2,'3rd Grade':3,'4th Grade':4,'5th Grade':5}

#map to invert the dictionary in order to get it back to text form
inv_map = {v: k for k, v in grade_to_index.items()}

#create columns with the index for the one or two grades. 
df['activity_grade_a_index']=df['activity_grade_a'].replace(grade_to_index)
df['activity_grade_b_index']=df['activity_grade_b'].replace(grade_to_index)

#get minimum of each row across the two columns; axis=1 says looks across columns
df['activity_min_grade_index'] = df[['activity_grade_a_index', 'activity_grade_b_index']].min(axis=1)

#group by node and get the minimum of activity-level minimums, map it to a new field
df['min_node_grade_index']=df.groupby('NODE_NAME')['activity_min_grade_index'].transform('min')

#get the grade back
df['min_node_grade']=df['min_node_grade_index'].replace(inv_map)`
```

Comment: you really need to provide a [mcve]. If you are asking about pandas, provide an example *input dataframe* and the corresponding *example output dataframe*. Don't give us vague descriptions

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! New poster here. I have edited the text to hopefully clarify. (I have read at least 5 StackExchange posts trying to figure out how to copy/paste a table into this post and they tell me to use Markdown format, but not how to achieve that. I've tried pasting it from Word...Notepad...I put it into a Jupyter Notebook markdown cell and copied from there...I tried a Latex table generator.... How do I get it into the right format?)

Comment: @CiviLearner you can print or save markdown with [`.to_markdown`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) like  *`print(df.loc[:5].to_markdown(index=False))`* ([view sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baKXf.png)). If you you paste that markdown in your question (make sure to leave an empty line before and after), then anyone can access it with [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) like *`pd.read_html(link_to_this_question)[0]`*

Comment: You can also use [`.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to covert the DataFrame to dictionary ([view sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qmCl.png)) [it's just a little bit better for preserving data-types], and then anyone could copy it and reproduce some of your `df`

Comment: Thanks! I used print(df.loc[:5].to_markdown(index=False))...but then I need to bring the data into something to sanitize it and remove IDs and such. So I exported the markdown to Jupyter Notebook and am attempting to work with it (insert 2 hours here...). I'll get there! Any way to take something from Excel and put it into Markdown?

Comment: @CiviLearner yes, you can just just use [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) first like `print(pd.read_excel(path_to_excel_file).to_markdown(index=False))` [include the `sheet_name` argument if you're reading from a file with multiple sheets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had `df` as below,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['STUDENT_ID', 'RECORD_ID', 'NODE_NAME', 'ACTIVITY_NAME', 'ACTIVITY_GRADE'],
    data=[  ['FredID', 'gobbledeegook1', 'Node1', 'MyActivity1', 'PreK, Kindergarten PreK'], 
            ['FredID', 'gobbledeegook2', 'Node1', 'MyActivity1', 'Kindergarten PreK'], 
            ['FredID', 'gobbledeegook3', 'Node2', 'MyActivity2', '1st Grade 1st Grade'], 
            ['JaniceID', 'gobbledeegook4', 'Node3', 'MyActivity3', 'Kindergarten Kindergarten'], 
            ['JaniceID', 'gobbledeegook5', 'Node3', 'MyActivity3', '1st Grade Preschool']    ]
)
```

<sup>(I altered the last row so that it doesn't look like the added column only has the minimum for that row in the final output.)</sup>

and a reference dictionary `index_to_grade`

```py
## I changed "Pre-K" to "PreK" since that's how it seems to be in your dataset
index_to_grade = {-2: 'Preschool', -1: 'PreK', 0: 'Kindergarten', 1: '1st Grade', 2: '2nd Grade', 3: '3rd Grade', 4: '4th Grade', 5: '5th Grade'}
# grade_to_index = {g: i for i, g in index_to_grade.items()} ## not needed for my solution
```

---

> *How can I create a function that will map the grade_to_index dictionary across each value of the comma-separated string that is ACTIVITY_GRADE, take the minimum for that activity, then group by node and take the min over the node's activities?*

You can write a function like

```py
def get_min_gi(grades:str, refDict=index_to_grade, defaultVal=None):
    inds = [i for i,g in refDict.items() if g in grades]
    return min(inds) if inds else defaultVal
```

and [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) it to `df['ACTIVITY_GRADE']`

```py
df['min_grade'] = df['ACTIVITY_GRADE'].apply(get_min_gi) ## will be over-written
min_node_grade_index = df.groupby('NODE_NAME')['min_grade'].transform('min')
df['min_grade'] = min_node_grade_index.map(index_to_grade) ## over-write
```

[image: opdf]

---

---

About why your code might not have worked:

> *`grade_to_index = {"Preschool": -2, "Pre-K": -1, ....`*

> *`FredID  gobbledeegook1  Node1   MyActivity1 PreK, Kindergarten  PreK`*

`grade_to_index` has key "Pre-K", but your sample dataset contains various instances of "PreK" (is it just a typo?)

---

And also,

> *`df.ACTIVITY_GRADE.str.split(",", expand = True)`* - ([view sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Hbs.png))

> *`df[___].replace(grade_to_index)`* - ([view sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAQiu.png))

The issue here is that not all you `ACTIVITY_GRADE` strings are properly comma-separated, so the `split` wouldn't work as intended; and even if they were comma separated, you should split by <kbd>`', '`</kbd> [at least for your sample data] because `.replace` will not work if there's extra whitespace around the keywords; and even then, you'd have more than 2 columns<sup>([view sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyLfv.png))</sup> as a result (row 1 has 3 grades), so the *`df[['activity_grade_a', 'activity_grade_b']] =`* part would raise error.

(That's why I prefer using a function like `get_min_gi` above since it should work for any number of grades.)

---

#### ADDED EDIT

> [image: desiredOp]

To get that, I would suggest something like

```py
# df['row_min_grade'] = df['ACTIVITY_GRADE'].apply(get_min_gi) # temporary 
df['row_min_grade'] = [min([grade_to_index.get(v,v) for v in i]) for i in df['ACTIVITY_GRADE'].str.split(","‌​)] # temporary 
df['min_node_grade'] = df.groupby('NODE_NAME')['row_min_grade'].transform('min').map(inv_map) 
df['min_activity_grade'] = df.groupby('ACTIVITY_NAME')['row_min_grade'].transform('min').map(inv_map)
df.drop(['row_min_grade'], axis='columns') # drop temporary column
```

Comment: Thanks!! Getting errors trying this (argument of type 'float' is not iterable). Deeply apologize for type-os; spent hours trying post fake data (see comments). There aren't leading strings.

Based on your response, trying:
temp_gr_list=df_has_activity['ACTIVITY_GRADE'].str.split(",")
#produces  [Kindergarten, PreK]. Nd to turn into indices and take min. Try
test_gr_index = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(grade_to_index), test_gr_list))  >>“'list' object has no attribute 'replace'”
test_gr_index =  [i.str.replace(grade_to_index) for i in test_gr_list] >>“'list' object has no attribute 'str'”

Comment: Update: I've spent two hours trying to reformat the data into a markup, sanitize it, and make it illustrative so that I could re-post the question, and I can't do it successfully. Can you please tell me: I really think that some combination of strip > make it a list > map the list to indexes > take the minimum is what I need, but I can't make it work. Help very much appreciated!

Comment: @CiviLearner about the *“'list' object has no attribute..."* errors, *`[Kindergarten, PreK]`* [or any other value in `temp_gr_list`, and I'm assuming the same for `test_gr_list` values] is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) so you can't treat them like pandas [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html)

Comment: .you could try something like `test_gr_index = [[grade_to_index.get(i,i) for v in i] for i in test_gr_list]` but note that you'll end up with a list of lists of indices, not a flat list of indices like you would with `test_gr_index = [min([grade_to_index.get(i,i) for v in i]) for i in test_gr_list]`

Comment: Also, you should keep in mind that [`str.replace`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace) is **NOT the same** as [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure how to get from your comment about "a list of lists with indices" to the minimum node grade-->  For a given node, I have a row 1 with activity_grade = Kindergarten, Pre-K, and row2 with activity_grade = Kindergarten, 1st Grade. **My goal is to get the node_min_grade = Pre-K**. How can I use split on activity_grade to turn them into a list e.g. [Pre-K, Kindregarten] then map the activity grades to an index e.g. [-1,0] -- this is the part that is erroring out-- ,then take the minimum by activity and then by node? Thanks!

Comment: @CiviLearner sounds very much like what my answer is doing [is it not giving your desired results?], but to break it down,

Comment: minimum grade index by row <--- `df['row_min_grInds'] = [min([grade_to_index.get(i,i) for v in i]) for i in test_gr_list]` [the flat list I mentioned before]

Comment: minimum grade index by activity <--- `df['activity_min_grInds'] = df.groupby('ACTIVITY_NAME')['row_min_grInds'].transform('min')` [this wasn't something I realized you wanted before]

Comment: minimum grade by node <--- `df['node_min_inds'] = df.groupby('NODE_NAME')['activity_min_grInds'].transform('min').map(inv_map)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252797/discussion-between-driftr95-and-civilearner).

Answer (score 1):

Including this in case another example will help you:

I made an activities.json to test:

```
{"STUDENT_ID": "FredID", "RECORD_ID": "gobbledeegook1", "NODE_NAME": "Node1", "ACTIVITY_NAME": "MyActivity1", "ACTIVITY_GRADE": "PreK, Kindergarten"}
{"STUDENT_ID": "FredID", "RECORD_ID": "gobbledeegook2", "NODE_NAME": "Node1", "ACTIVITY_NAME": "MyActivity1", "ACTIVITY_GRADE": "Kindergarten"}
{"STUDENT_ID": "FredID", "RECORD_ID": "gobbledeegook3", "NODE_NAME": "Node2", "ACTIVITY_NAME": "MyActivity2", "ACTIVITY_GRADE": "1st Grade"}
{"STUDENT_ID": "JaniceID", "RECORD_ID": "gobbledeegook4", "NODE_NAME": "Node3", "ACTIVITY_NAME": "MyActivity3", "ACTIVITY_GRADE": "Kindergarten"}
{"STUDENT_ID": "JaniceID", "RECORD_ID": "gobbledeegook5", "NODE_NAME": "Node3", "ACTIVITY_NAME": "MyActivity3", "ACTIVITY_GRADE": "1st Grade"}
```

and then create a dictionary (nodes) with key values for each node and a set of grades listed for these nodes. I used .strip() when iterating over the grades:list() produced by .split(',') because sometimes there is whitespace (i.e. " Kindergarten"):

```
import pandas as pd
path = "activities.jsonl"
df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf=path, lines=True, orient='records')

nodes = dict()
for i in range(len(df)):
    currNode = df["NODE_NAME"][i]
    grades = df["ACTIVITY_GRADE"][i].split(',')
    if currNode not in nodes:
        nodes[currNode] = set()
    for grade in grades:
        nodes[currNode].add(grade.strip())
# {'Node1': {'Kindergarten', 'PreK'}, 'Node2': {'1st Grade'}, 'Node3': {'Kindergarten', '1st Grade'}}
indices = {"Preschool": -2, "PreK": -1, "Kindergarten": 0, "1st Grade": 1, "2nd Grade": 2, "3rd Grade": 3, "4th Grade": 4, "5th Grade": 5}
minGrades = dict()
for node in nodes:
    currMin = ""
    currIndex = 10
    for grade in nodes[node]:
        if indices[grade] < currIndex:
            currIndex = indices[grade]
            currMin = grade
    minGrades[node] = currMin

df['MIN_NODE_GRADE'] = [None for i in range(len(df))]
for i in range(len(df)):
    currNode = df["NODE_NAME"][i]
    minGrade = minGrades[currNode]
    df['MIN_NODE_GRADE'][i] = minGrade

print(df)
```

which produces the updated df:

```
  STUDENT_ID       RECORD_ID  ...      ACTIVITY_GRADE MIN_NODE_GRADE
0     FredID  gobbledeegook1  ...  PreK, Kindergarten           PreK
1     FredID  gobbledeegook2  ...        Kindergarten           PreK
2     FredID  gobbledeegook3  ...           1st Grade      1st Grade
3   JaniceID  gobbledeegook4  ...        Kindergarten   Kindergarten
4   JaniceID  gobbledeegook5  ...           1st Grade   Kindergarten
```

-- I also assumed "PreK" was a typo.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am not advanced enough to understand it and therefore troubleshoot it... I don't know how to work with json's, and I would need to export my dataframe as a json and then re-import it in order to test this. But I'm sure it works well for those who are more advanced!

Comment: I just used the json to make the dataframe -- after that, it should work the same! But, I get you--it's a bit more code xD